# Jquery selector for html select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently working jquery selector I have a query on how to find html select drop down using jquery selector for input text I am finding for in this way is that possible to combine html select drop down with this `.find("input[type='text']"` but I want to know how to find html select drop down. I tried `select[name=bar]` but in my code i have more than 4 html drop down and i don't want to give like this.

Any suggestion please help me

here is my jquery code

```
function bind_change_events(){
    $('.cloned_field').on('input',function(e){ 
        if($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
        {
            //$(this).removeClass("cloned_field");
            $(this).addClass("required_field");
            var parent_div = $(this).closest("div.cloned-row1,div.cloned-row2,div.cloned-row3,div.cloned-row4,div.cloned-row5").find("input");
            parent_div.each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("required_field");
            });
        } 
        check_for_validation_removal($(this));
        bind_validation();
    });
}

function check_for_validation_removal(element){
    var parent_div = $(element).closest("div.cloned-row1,div.cloned-row2,div.cloned-row3,div.cloned-row4,div.cloned-row5").find("input[type='text']");
    console.log(parent_div);
    console.log(parent_div.length);
    var invalid_ele = 0;
    parent_div.each(function () { 
        if($(this).val().trim().length == 0){
                invalid_ele = invalid_ele + 1;
        }  
    });
    console.log(invalid_ele);
    if(parent_div.length == invalid_ele){
        parent_div.each(function () { 
            $(this).removeClass("required_field"); 
            $(this).rules('remove'); 
         });
        bind_validation();
        update_errors();
    }
    var parent_div1 = $(element).closest("div.cloned-row1,div.cloned-row2,div.cloned-row3,div.cloned-row4,div.cloned-row5").find("input[type='text']");

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What the problem with `find("input[type='text'], select")`

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: actually i want to add $(this).addClass("required_field"); in the validation but this is wa not happening for html select drop down it was happening only for input text field

Comment: if you want to select the selected option use `$('idofselect option:selected').attr('id') or .val()`

Comment: @Pekka the problem is there any generic way like text because if i gave with id i have 5 drop down overall in my page the line of code will be lenghtier

Comment: `$('idofselect option:selected').text()`